# Cosmos DB .NET SDK order by a dynamic field (parameterized)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I use the .NET SDK to retrieve some items in a Cosmos DB instance using continuationTokens to be able to retrieve paginated pieces of data. So far this works.

I use a generic Get function to retrieve the items:

```csharp
var query = container.GetItemQueryIterator<T>(
    new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c"),
    continuationToken: continuationToken,
    requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
    {
        MaxItemCount = itemCount
    });
```

However I would like to add a dynamic order by field where the callee can decide on which field the results should be ordered. I tried adding a parameterized field like:

```csharp
new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM c order by @orderBy")
   .WithParameter("@orderBy", "fieldname")
```

But this does not work, I keep getting Syntax errors while executing, is it actually possible to dynamically add an order by clause?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the fully qualified field name? Something like c.fieldName?

Comment: @GauravMantri Yes, I tried that also, still a syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .WithParameter() fluent syntax can only be used with the WHERE clause in QueryDefinition so you will have to construct your sql with the order by appended dynamically to the sql string.

One thing to keep in mind is that unless this is a small workload with less than 20GB of data, this container will not scale unless you use the partition key in your queries. The other consideration here too is that order by gets much better performance when you using composite indexes. But if there are a wide number of properties that results can be sorted on, writes may get very expensive from all of the individual composite indexes.

In all cases, if this is meant to scale you should measure and benchmark high concurrency operations.

Comment: Thanks for the info about the partition key, in the real code, I use the partition key, but for brevity of the question I simplified the code a little bit. 
Regarding the dynamically appending of the SQL string, that is my current workaround. However how do you prevent SQL injection when the string's origin is user entered?

Comment: You can only read data using Cosmos' SQL so SQL injection doesn't matter.